# How to consume WCF in JQuery Eclipce

Tags: c#, jquery

i am trying to consume my Wcf in eclipce to complete my phonegap app so...
i have try to consume it in VS 2010 HTML file and it works find

**In VS 2010:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.getJSON("MobileService.svc/DoWorks", function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                  alert(data[i].Name + " " + data[i].Age);
              }
          });
      });
  
  </script>
  <!--<style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>-->
</head>
<body>
  <!--<div id="images"></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

**in Eclipce**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>a</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.getJSON("192.168.3.113/MobileServiceProject1/MobileService.svc/DoWorks", function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                  alert(data[i].Name + " " + data[i].Age);
              }
          });
      });
  
  </script>
 </head>
 <body><br></body>
</html>
```

AS I have use the full path of the service that i use it when i call it from the browser

URL:
92.168.3.113/MobileServiceProject1/MobileService.svc/DoWorks

```
Response:
[{"Age":"23","Name":"Shaheen"},{"Age":"26","Name":"Khaled"},{"Age":"20","Name":"Ahmed"},{"Age":"30","Name":"Ibraheem"}]
```

so what I have forget ...I try to search for some thing and I found but no one help me .. Please HELP

Comment: Is your WCF service deployed to an IIS/standalone host when you run the Eclipse code?

Comment: yes i have Publish the project on iis when i run Eclipse